# 500.19 internal server error

Tags: system, internal

I am currently trying to add Blogengine to a web page. I have used web platform installer. when I try to view the blog it gives me this error.

```
Module IIS Web Core 
Notification Unknown 
Handler Not yet determined 
Error Code 0x80070005 
Config Error Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions  
Config File \\?\c:...\httpdocs\web.config 
Requested URL http://..../Blog/ 
Physical Path  
Logon Method Not yet determined 
Logon User Not yet determined
```

I have given read permisions to the web.config file but it still doesn't run